# What's the quickest way to test if an object is IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Is there a quick way to find out if an `object` variable's contents supports IEnumerable? Specifically I'm using `XPathEvaluate()` from System.Xml.XPath, which can return "[An object that can contain a bool, a double, a string, or an IEnumerable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx)"

So after executing:

```
XDocument content = XDocument.Load("foo.xml");
object action = content.XPathEvaluate("/bar/baz/@quux");
// Do I now call action.ToString(), or foreach(var foo in action)?
```

I could poke around with `action.GetType().GetInterface()`, but I thought I'd ask if there's a quicker/easier way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are looking for the [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator:

```
if(action is IEnumerable)
```

or even better, the [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator.

```
IEnumerable enumerable = (action as IEnumerable);
if(enumerable != null)
{
  foreach(var item in enumerable)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that `string` also implements `IEnumerable`, so you might like to extend that check to `if(enumerable != null && !(action is string))`

Comment: Be aware of the fact that `string` implements `IEnumerable` too. Especially when your object might be a string (like return value of `XPathEvaluate`) and you actually want to know if you have a _collection_ you might use an extended check like `if (action is IEnumerable && !(action is string))`

Comment: @Alex very true.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
if(action is IEnumerable)
```

This is what it does:

> An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to test if an object is of a type then use `is`. If you need to use that object after use `as` so that the runtime must only do the cast once:

```
IEnumerable e = action as IEnumerable

if(null != e)
{
    // Use e.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    action is IEnumerable;
```

Comment: I think a little more explanation or more fully developed code would've gotten you some votes.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
if(action is IENumerable)
{
  //do some stuff
}
```

hth

Answer (score -3):

I am receiving an array of sql parameters, lots of them are Enum Values.

The only way to check if an element is part of an enum has been:

```
 if(parameterArrayList[0].Value.GetType().BaseType.Name == "Enum")
     Console.WriteLine("Yeah");
 else
     Console.WriteLine("Meh");
```

Comment: This is an answer to an entirely different question. (It's also a brittle one - there could be a different type called `Enum`.  Using `....GetType().IsEnum` would be more robust.)

Comment: OP asked about `IEnumerable`, not `Enum`